# I get Exit code 0 but the program doesn't do what i want. Looks like it gets stuck in the first line of code

Tags: python, input

When running the program i get exit code 0 but it doesnt execute the whole function/code. It seems it just runs the first line...any ideas on how to solve this? many thanks in advance!

```
import random

def mastermind():

    #asking for length
    length=int(input("chain length of 2 to 9: "))

    #generating random chain of 2 to 9 numbers according to user's demand:
    chain=[]
    for number in range(length+1):
        chain_nr=random.randint(1,9)
        chain.append(chain_nr)
    return chain


    #guessed chain
    guessed_chain = int(input("guessed chain: "))
    guessed_count = 0
    for nr in guessed_chain:
        if nr in chain and nr == chain[0]:
            guessed_count +=1
            print(f'"you\'ve guessed" {guessed_count}"numbers of the chain"')
        else:
            print("you haven't guessed any number")

mastermind()
```

Comment: The `# guessed chain` part of your code is unreachable since you have a `return chain` before it.

Comment: many thanks for the swift reply! looks like there is some other problem in the code but removing this return statement has solved this first problem.

Comment: If removing the return statement solved the first problem, then you forgot to mention, that the program printed out
`"chain length of 2 to 9: "` You said, that only the first line (`import random`) was executed.

DIfficult to help if you give incomplete information

Comment: you have to add an if statement, that 'breaks' the for loop of you found the complete solution

Comment: thanks gelonida! just landed in this coding world and i will take into account your comments, just seen i need to be more precise! thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers replied, the error is in the return clause, where it should be removed (as it temrinates the execution), as well as the need to cast the second input to str in order to iterate and compare. However, the *input* clause already returns a string, so you could either cast the first input to str or cast each value of the second input to int when comparing. 
Also, if you wanted to compare each chain of numbers character-wise (first one to first one, and so on), the logic of your program is wrong (it's comparing each element of the second chain to only the first value of the first random chain!).

Here is the code, with a print statement of the first chain in order to debug.

```
import random

def mastermind():

    #asking for length
    length=int(input("chain length of 2 to 9: "))

    #generating random chain of 2 to 9 numbers according to user's demand:
    chain=[]
    for number in range(length+1):
        chain_nr=random.randint(1,9)
        chain.append(chain_nr)

    print(chain)

    #guessed chain
    guessed_chain = input("guessed chain: ")
    guessed_count = 0
    for i, nr in enumerate(guessed_chain):
        if int(nr) in chain and int(nr) == chain[i]:
            guessed_count +=1
            print(f'"you\'ve guessed" {guessed_count}"numbers of the chain"')
        else:
            print("you haven't guessed any number")

mastermind()
```

EDIT: here is a more pythonic way to construct the random chain of integers, using list comprehension.

```
chain=[random.randint(1,9) for i in range(length+1)]
```

Comment: i see, many thanks for clarifying! really happy with this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the `return` statement from the middle of your code. Calling a return statement makes your code exit the function, and return the chain that you generated. There is no need for that.

If you run this without the return statement you will encounter another error. The next user input should be of type string and not int, hence you will need to parse it as such with `str()` rather than `int()` as something of type int is not iterable.

```
import random

def mastermind():

    #asking for length
    length=int(input("chain length of 2 to 9: "))

    #generating random chain of 2 to 9 numbers according to user's demand:
    chain=[]
    for number in range(length+1):
        chain_nr=random.randint(1,9)
        chain.append(chain_nr)

    # no need for the return statement here 

    #guessed chain
    guessed_chain = str(input("guessed chain: "))
    guessed_count = 0
    for nr in guessed_chain:
        if nr in chain and nr == chain[0]:
            guessed_count +=1
            print(f'"you\'ve guessed" {guessed_count}"numbers of the chain"')
        else:
            print("you haven't guessed any number")

mastermind()
```

Also for the future, try to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code, and explain why you think it is showing you an error, what you did and not just the what the error is.

Comment: If this solved your problem consider marking this answer as correct and closing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i see in the console:

```
I imported
mastermind will be called
chain length of 2 to 9: 5
guessed chain: 456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/Part3ej2.py", line 28, in <module>
    mastermind()
  File "E:/Python/Part3ej2.py", line 21, in mastermind
    for nr in guessed_chain:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: perhaps better to ask another question?
The problem which you're having now doesn't really match the title of the question.

Try

`guessed_chain = [int(digit) for digit in input("guessed chain: ")]`